# Which translation of 41:24 is correct according to Hilali-Khan

Tags: quran-translation

In my dead tree copy (Sixteenth Revised Edition, Darussalam Publishing 1997) of Hilali-Khan's Noble Qur'an, 41:24 is translated as follows:

> Then, if they bear the torment patiently, then the Fire is the home for them, and if they seek to please Allâh, yet they are not of those who will ever be allowed to please Allâh.

However, according to quran.com, the Muhsin Khan translation of the same ayah is,

> Then, if they have patience, yet the Fire will be a home for them, and if they beg for to be excused, yet they are not of those who will ever be excused.

Presumably one of these translations was determined to be more correct than the other, hence the change, and logically it would be the most recent one.  However, I am unable to find any indication as to which version is being used on quran.com, so I have no way of knowing which of the two translations is actually *newer*.

So the question lies: **According to the Hilali-Khan translation, what is currently considered the correct translation of this ayah** (i.e. which is being printed in *current* editions of the book)?  Bonus points for anyone who can also explain why exactly the change was made, and why the new version is now considered *more* correct than the original.

Comment: I have a 1995 revised version and it uses the second translation you've posted.

Comment: It is like direct and in-direct narration to me. Both are same to me.